# CheckBoxPreference - set summaryOn

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, checkboxpreference

I got a problem with my PreferenceActivity.
I'm using XML mainly, but some Preferences I add via code, that all works fine.

But I ran into a problem.
I added a CheckBoxPreference programmatically - that works.
But I'd like to set the summaryOn and summaryOff for it.
Android Studio doesn't suggest it, only setSummary, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSpNQ.png). (can't post pics yet)

I hope you can help me, otherwise the UX wouldn't be consistent.

Thanks,
kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you declare `myRecCheckBox` as a `Preference`. Declare the `myRecCheckbox` as a `CheckBoxPreference` and it should work.

Comment: edit: thought you meant the "new Preference", but in fact, you were right, thanks!!!